Quartz reschedule only works half
I'm trying to reschedule my trigger (only got one in this project), in my C# Blazor app.
My problem is that the execution change works, but information such as interval and previous firetime are no longer displayed. If I start the trigger from the beginning, it gets this.
In Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddQuartz(c =>
    {
        var sensorKey = new JobKey("sensorKey");
        c.AddJob<SensorJob>(c => c.WithIdentity(sensorKey));
        c.AddTrigger(opts => opts
            .ForJob(sensorKey)
            .WithIdentity("SensorJob-trigger")                
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(60)
                .RepeatForever())
            .StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10)));
    });
builder.Services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

In settings.razor where I try to change the interval:
@page "/settings"
@using Quartz
@inject ISchedulerFactory SchedulerFactory

...
<h5 class="card-title">CronJob Informationen:</h5>
<p class="card-text"><strong>Next execute:</strong> @nextFireTime</p>
<p class="card-text"><strong>Last execute:</strong> @previousFireTime</p>
<p class="card-text"><strong>Interval:</strong> @repeatInterval</p>
<p class="card-text"><strong>Times triggered:</strong> @triggerDescription</p>
<p class="card-text"><strong>Status:</strong> @(triggerIsPaused ? "Inactiv" : "Activ")</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PauseScheduler">Paus CronJob</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="ShowChangeIntervallModal">Change interval</button>

...
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _scheduler = await SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    var sensorTrigger = await _scheduler.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey("SensorJob-trigger"));

    if (sensorTrigger != null)
    {
        var triggerDetail = sensorTrigger as ISimpleTrigger;
        triggerIsPaused = await _scheduler.GetTriggerState(new TriggerKey("SensorJob-trigger")) == TriggerState.Paused ? true : false;
        nextFireTime = sensorTrigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc()?.LocalDateTime.ToString("g") ?? "N/A";
        previousFireTime = sensorTrigger.GetPreviousFireTimeUtc()?.LocalDateTime.ToString("g") ?? "N/A";
        repeatInterval = triggerDetail?.RepeatInterval.TotalHours.ToString("F2") + " Hours" ?? "N/A";
        triggerDescription = triggerDetail?.TimesTriggered.ToString() ?? "N/A";
    }
}

...
var currentTrigger = await _scheduler.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey("SensorJob-trigger"));

if (currentTrigger != null)
{
    var newTrigger = currentTrigger.GetTriggerBuilder()
        .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(modalInputValue))
        .Build();
     await _scheduler.RescheduleJob(currentTrigger.Key, newTrigger);
}

After I called this code, the interval get changed, but information like previousFireTime and repeatInterval are no longer available.
Tried to force refresh the site
